# Supporting special characters with str_word_count()

Tags: php, utf-8

The [str_word_count()](http://php.net/str_word_count) function returns an array that holds all words in a string. It works great, except when using special characters. In this case, the php script receives the string via querystring:

When i open:
[http://localhost/index.php?q=this%20wórds](http://localhost/index.php?q=this%20w%C3%B3rds)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
print_r(str_word_count($_GET['q'],1,'ó'));
```

Instead of returning:

```
[0] this
[1] wórds
```

...it returns:

```
[0] this
[1] w
[2] rds
```

How could this function support those special characters that are being sent through querystring?

**Update** - it worked out just fine by using [mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario)'s solution:

```
function sanitize_words($string) {
    preg_match_all("/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}'\x{2019}]*/u",$string,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if that third parameter is sufficient to make `str_word_count` work for non-ASCII symbols. It probably only works with `Latin-1` if anything.

As alternative you could count the words with a regex however:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\pL+/u', $_GET['q'], $matches);
```

This works for UTF-8 at least. To fully replicate `str_word_count` you might need `[\pL']+` eventually.

Comment: It worked great too. What would be the difference between the 1st and 2nd regex? Can't get the 2nd one to work.

Comment: The second one would allow for things like `isn't` to be counted as single word. The complete regex is `'/[\pL']+/u'` of course. There's another version in the manual http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php#85592 which probably covers all the other typographical variants of what should be considered a word.

Comment: how could this regex return only words that are longer than 1 character?

Comment: With `{2,}` in place of `+` or `{1,}` instead of `*`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 2):

All possible combinations:

```
$diacritics = 'aàȁáâǎãāăȃȧäåẚảạḁąᶏậặầằắấǻẫẵǡǟẩẳⱥæǽǣᴂꬱꜳꜵꜷꜹꜻꜽɐɑꭤᶐꬰɒͣᵃªᵄᵆᵅᶛᴬᴭᴀᴁₐbḃƅƀᵬɓƃḅḇᶀꞗȸßẞꞵꞛꞝᵇᵝᴮᴯʙᴃᵦcćĉčċƈçḉɕꞔꞓȼ¢ʗᴐᴒɔꜿᶗꝢꝣ©ͨᶜᶝᵓᴄdďḋᵭðđɗᶑḓḍḏḑᶁɖȡꝱǳʣǆʤʥȸǲǅꝺẟƍƌͩᵈᶞᵟᴰᴅᴆeèȅéēêěȇĕẽėëẻḙḛẹȩęᶒⱸệḝềḕếḗễểɇəǝɘɚᶕꬲꬳꬴᴔꭁꭂ•ꜫɛᶓȝꜣꝫɜᴈᶔɝɞƩͤᵉᵊᵋᵌᶟᴱᴲᴇⱻₑₔfẜẝƒꬵḟẛᶂᵮꞙꝭꝼʩꟻﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄᶠꜰgǵḡĝǧğġģǥꬶᵷɡᶃɠꞡᵍᶢᴳɢʛhħĥȟḣḧɦɧḫḥẖḩⱨꜧꞕƕɥʮʯͪʰʱꭜᶣᵸꟸᴴʜₕiìȉíīĩîǐȋĭïỉɨḭịįᶖḯıɩɪꭠꭡᴉᵻᵼĳỻİꟾꟷͥⁱᶤᶦᵎᶧᶥᴵᵢjȷĵǰɉɟʝĳʲᶡᶨᴶᴊⱼkḱǩꝁꝃꝅƙḳḵⱪķᶄꞣʞĸᵏᴷᴋₖlĺľŀłꝉƚⱡɫꬷꬸɬꬹḽḷḻļɭȴᶅꝲḹꞎꝇꞁỻǈǉʪʫɮˡᶩᶪꭝꭞᶫᴸʟᴌₗmḿṁᵯṃɱᶆꝳꬺꭑᴟɯɰꟺꟿꟽͫᵐᶬᶭᴹᴍₘnǹńñňŉṅᵰṇṉṋņŋɳɲƞꬻꬼȵᶇꝴꞃꞑꞥᴝᴞǋǌⁿᵑᶯᶮᶰᴺᴻɴᴎₙoᴏᴑòȍóǿőōõôȏǒŏȯöỏơꝍọǫⱺꝋɵøᴓǭộợồṑờốṍṓớỗỡṏȭȱȫổởœɶƣɸƍꝏʘꬽꬾꬿꭀꭁꭂꭃꭄꭢꭣ∅ͦᵒᶱºꟹᶲᴼᴽₒpṕṗꝕꝓᵽᵱᶈꝑþꝥꝧƥƪƿȹꟼᵖᴾᴘᴩᵨₚqʠɋꝙꝗȹꞯʘθᶿrŕȑřȓṙɍᵲꝵꞧṛŗṟᶉꞅɼɽṝɾᵳᴦɿſⱹɹɺɻ®ꝶꭇꭈꭉꭊꭋꭌͬʳʶʴʵᴿʀʁᴙᴚꭆᵣsśŝšṡᵴꞩṣşșȿʂᶊṩṥṧƨʃʄʆᶋᶘꭍʅƪﬅﬆˢᶳᶴꜱₛtťṫẗƭⱦᵵŧꝷṱṯṭţƫʈțȶʇꞇꜩʦʧʨᵺͭᵗᶵᵀᴛₜuùȕúűūũûǔȗŭüůủưꭒʉꞹṷṵụṳųᶙɥựǜừṹǘứǚữṻǖửʊᵫᵿꭎꭏꭐꭑͧᵘᶶᶷᵙᶸꭟᵁᴜᵾᵤvṽⱱⱴꝟṿᶌʋʌͮᵛⱽᶹᶺᴠᵥwẁẃŵẇẅẘⱳẉꝡɯɰꟽꟿʍʬꞶꞷʷᵚᶭᵂᴡxẋẍᶍ×ꭓꭔꭕꭖꭗꭘꭙˣ˟ᵡₓᵪyỳýȳỹŷẏÿẙỷƴɏꭚỵỿɣɤꝩʎƛ¥ʸˠᵞʏᵧzźẑžżƶᵶẓẕʐᶎʑȥⱬɀʒǯʓƺᶚƹꝣᵹᶻᶼᶽᶾᴢᴣ';
str_word_count($string, 1, $diacritics);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just

```
print_r( str_word_count($_GET['q'],1) ); ?
```

You can also explode( ' ', $string ) on the string and count( $array );

Comment: Wouldn't work. if you don't set an allowed charlist, the ó that i'm trying to include, won't be returned as part of the word. The explode() solution sounds nice, but does not cover all cases. For example: words.separated by.dots

Comment: If you need dots as a separator, you can use $result = preg_split('/[. ]/', $subject); That will use spaces or dots as the delimeter.

Comment: the problem is that i cannot depend on the user input. if they want they might add strings like this:

Comment: Just a hyphen? Can't you validate for string length too?

Comment: sorry, that last comment was incomplete. I meant: "hello- this @is someone %&^$*$ that lik3s to writ3 with stránge and $pecial characters."

Comment: actually the best scenario is a str_word_count() with utf8 support hehe, but i think i'll have to go with the explode() approach and make some string sanitization afterwards.

Comment: one last question, how could I implement the preg_split() approach with both dots and spaces?

Comment: That one that I supplied will do that... just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 1):

for German language use this :

```
str_word_count($file, 1, 'ÄäÖöÜüß');
```

for all other languages - just to replace the special characters with yours (French, Polish etc...)